# Breeze wont detect entities changes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, breeze

I can't get breeze.savechanges() to detect entities changes. All i want is to simply create new **order->orderdetails** related entities, modify it then savechanges but failing terribly, so i have breeze manager in a factory named **data** and this is my controller

```
angular.module("InventoryApp")
    .controller("PurchasesCtrl", function ($scope, data, $log) {
    var setFields=function(){
        var product = data.createEntity("Product");
        var purchaseOrder=data.createEntity("PurchaseOrder");
        $scope.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;
        $scope.product = product;  //binding entities to view for edits
    };


    $scope.save = function(product, purchaseOrder) { //i am calling this from view
        purchaseOrder.Time = new Date();
        product.PurchaseOrders.push(purchaseOrder); //creating a relation
        data.saveChanges();   //breeze refuses to save claim it have no changes
        setFields();   //binding new fresh enties
    };

    setFields(); //binding new entities to view for edits
});
```

I have tried `data.saveChanges([product,purchaseOrder])` but i the relationship between product and purchase becomes somewhat lost and server returns validation error in purchaseOrder that it must have a valid product (it doesn't assosiate the new product i sent with it?)

`data.saveChanges([product])` will only save the product and ignore PurchaseOrder despite `product.PurchaseOrders.push(purchaseOrder);` working.

using `purchaseOrder.Product=product;` instead of `product.PurchaseOrders.push(purchaseOrder);` to creating a relation provides the same story.

Either ways the relation appears perfect offline while debugging with dev tools but breeze manager hasChanges frag wont turn true and the server the error above when i send entities by force.

I doubt Metadata to be the problem as it was server generated kept it on Metadata.js and fed to the app during app.run but here it is metadata.

```
{
    "schema": {
        "namespace": "Inventory.API",
        "alias": "Self",
        "annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes": "false",
        "xmlns:annotation": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation",
        "xmlns:customannotation": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation",
        "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm",
        "cSpaceOSpaceMapping": "[\"Inventory.API.Product\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.Product\"],[\"Inventory.API.PurchaseOrder\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.PurchaseOrder\"],[\"Inventory.API.SellOrder\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.SellOrder\"]",
        "entityType": [{
            "name": "Product",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.Product, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "BarCode",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "maxLength": "Max",
                "fixedLength": "false",
                "unicode": "true"
            }, {
                "name": "Name",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "maxLength": "Max",
                "fixedLength": "false",
                "unicode": "true"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": [{
                "name": "PurchaseOrders",
                "relationship": "Self.PurchaseOrder_Product",
                "fromRole": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Target",
                "toRole": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Source"
            }, {
                "name": "SellOrders",
                "relationship": "Self.SellOrder_Product",
                "fromRole": "SellOrder_Product_Target",
                "toRole": "SellOrder_Product_Source"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "PurchaseOrder",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.PurchaseOrder, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "Time",
                "type": "Edm.DateTime",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "TotalPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": {
                "name": "Product",
                "relationship": "Self.PurchaseOrder_Product",
                "fromRole": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Source",
                "toRole": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Target"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "SellOrder",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.SellOrder, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "Time",
                "type": "Edm.DateTime",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "TotalPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": {
                "name": "Product",
                "relationship": "Self.SellOrder_Product",
                "fromRole": "SellOrder_Product_Source",
                "toRole": "SellOrder_Product_Target"
            }
        }],
        "entityContainer": {
            "name": "InventoryContext",
            "customannotation:UseClrTypes": "true",
            "entitySet": [{
                "name": "Products",
                "entityType": "Self.Product"
            }, {
                "name": "PurchaseOrders",
                "entityType": "Self.PurchaseOrder"
            }, {
                "name": "SellOrders",
                "entityType": "Self.SellOrder"
            }],
            "associationSet": [{
                "name": "PurchaseOrder_Product",
                "association": "Self.PurchaseOrder_Product",
                "end": [{
                    "role": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Source",
                    "entitySet": "PurchaseOrders"
                }, {
                    "role": "PurchaseOrder_Product_Target",
                    "entitySet": "Products"
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "SellOrder_Product",
                "association": "Self.SellOrder_Product",
                "end": [{
                    "role": "SellOrder_Product_Source",
                    "entitySet": "SellOrders"
                }, {
                    "role": "SellOrder_Product_Target",
                    "entitySet": "Products"
                }]

            }]
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you missed any relation between Product and PurchaseOrders?

Comment: @Shohel No.. I dont think so, the relation is enforced thats why i cant save PurchaseOrder not having valid Product

Comment: Is Product <-> PurchaseOrder a many-to-many relationship?  If so, you will have to map the association table (PurchaseOrderProduct) so that breeze can add the association entity to set the relationship.

Comment: There is no option as far as I know, I have used this issue by changing of breeze.debug.js, Here is the js link http://plnkr.co/edit/lUwR2dfBbsdwcLWU3acy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks i am tying it now